# Как в FACEBOOK сформировать список всех лайкнувших посты написанные от имен страницы на других станицах или группах?

Tags: facebook, like

Сейчас в ФБ есть возможность комментировать записи от имени страницы.
Потом приходит намопиналка, что вашу запись лайнули ХХ человек, кликаешь, и там уже не разобрать, кто что и где лайкнул.

Но если перейти по ссылочке с лайками, то открывается окно, к котором есть список лайнкнувших, и кнопочка пригласить..

**ВОПРОС**

Как можно получить отчет/реестр/окно ( не знаю как в ФБ это называется правильно) всех лайкнувших ваши записи, что бы не "лазить" по зписям и в ручную искать кто что лайнул?

Обратил внимание, что все ссылки на лайки от имен страницы имеют одинаковый код, кроме набор внутри ссылки вида

[https://www.facebook.com/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/?ft_ent_identifier=НАБОРКАКИХТОСИМВОЛОВ=16тизначноеЧИСЛОодинковое](https://www.facebook.com/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/?ft_ent_identifier=%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%A5%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%98%D0%9C%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%92=16%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%A7%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5).

Может быть есть какой то чудо запрос. который выведет всех лайкнувших все посты... в одном окне?...

За ранее спасибо за подсказку!

Answer (score 0):

Обзор статистики
[https://m.facebook.com/(название](https://m.facebook.com/(%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) вашей страницы)/insights/?referrer=page_insights_tab_button

https://www.facebook.com/analytics/ 
Здесь все отчёты. Все настраивается (доки там же)   также есть мобильное приложение.

NotaBene ваш вопрос оффтоп. Вам лучше спросить подобные вопросы на qna.habr.ru или Яндекс.кью

Comment: Дело а том, что там общая информация, а речь идет именно о реестре, который помог бы вывести отчет с кнопкой добавить все тек кто лйкнул сообщения от имени страниц, на ДРУГИХ страницах и в ДРУГИХ группах! Может быть есть какой то скрипт, то что вы привели, в пример, не содержит данного отчет... речь про это!